# ruby on rails active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

For this method I am having an issue with the while loop. If I enter a username that already exists it is supposed to prompt me again to enter another username but what is going on is that it is skipping that part and jumping straight to prompt for the user to enter a password.

```rb
def create_account
  # You can assign the 'get' method results to a var if you want
  puts "Enter your full name"
  get_full_name = gets.chomp

  puts 'Enter your email address'
  get_email = gets.chomp

  puts 'Enter your desired username.'
  get_username = gets.chomp

  while Customer.exists?(username: get_username) do
    puts "This username is already taken. Please enter a different one"
    get_username = gets.chomp
    break if !Customer.exists?(username: get_username)
  end

  puts "Please enter password"
  get_password = gets.chomp

  customer = Customer.create(
    first_last_name: get_full_name,
    email_address:   get_email,
    username:        get_username,
    password:        get_password)
end
```

Comment: Are you sure if `Customer.create` successfully executed?

Comment: Why don't you use ActiveRecord's validations instead of that Costumer.exists? condition? You can set the uniqueness of the username instead and loop until you have no error on that attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will only enter the loop if there is already a customer existing with those credentials. Can you confirm that a customer with that name already exists, and there there are no validation errors like @SujaAdiga suggests?

You can test it out with the following:

```
    def create_account
  # You can assign the 'get' method results to a var if you want
  puts "Enter your full name"
  get_full_name = gets.chomp

  puts 'Enter your email address'
  get_email = gets.chomp

  puts 'Enter your desired username.'
  get_username = gets.chomp


  ## It will only enter the lop if such a customer already exists.
  ## Let's add one:

customer = Customer.create(
    first_last_name: get_full_name,
    email_address:   get_email,
    username:        get_username,
    password:        "password")

if customer.errors.full_messages.empty?
  puts "******successfully created customer*******"
  puts customer
else
  puts "*****ok we could not create the customer*****"
end

  while Customer.exists?(username: get_username) do
    puts "This username is already taken. Please enter a different one"
    get_username = gets.chomp
    break if !Customer.exists?(username: get_username)
  end

  puts "Please enter password"
  get_password = gets.chomp

  customer = Customer.create(
    first_last_name: get_full_name,
    email_address:   get_email,
    username:        get_username,
    password:        get_password)
end
```